# Deploy a Lua App on Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service

I have [this](https://github.com/robinsloan/rnn-writer) app working on my system. I just deployed it on azure app services through Azure CLI.

On my machine, the app runs (server.lua -gpu -1) on localhost as an api but on the deployed url, I get HTTP 500 error.

```
This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.

For more information about HTTP errors, see Help.
```

But The resource Heath says that:

```
The Web app is running normally
```

Also, I did not follow any steps like in [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/) as I am not sure what it would be in my lua app. Is anything required besides pushing my app in the git repository to azure?

What would be the steps to deploy my api **successfully** (I tried to put all info above.)? Thanks.

Comment: How do you run that locally? There's no Lua runtime in Azure App Service so not sure i understand your question. Maybe you could get it going with HTTP Platform Handler, but it's a MAYBE - https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/The-HTTP-Platform-Handler-with-Scott-Hanselman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think **LUA** is supported on Azure App Service. There is a project on **Github** here: https://github.com/shibayan/iislua

This is for setting up LUA on IIS. I doubt if this can be done on Azure App Service as it wont allow you to install a MSI.